# Sort custom date in datatables

Tags: sorting, date, datatables

I am using datatable to show result in table.

[image]

When I click on sort it sort date by day and ignores month and year.

ascending 
[image]

descending
[image]

Code that I am using at the moment is

```
 $('.dtbt2').DataTable({
    "ordering" : true,
    "scrollCollapse" : true,
    "columnDefs" : [{"targets":3, "type":"date-eu"}],
    "bInfo": true
});
```

What should I do to sort correctly?

Thanks you nice people in advance,
Auj

Answer (score 0):

Is type : date-eu an out of box datatables data type? I have never used it. But if it's not, try using the extend function like [this example](http://code.buzzword-cloud.com/post/2017/05/23/jquery-datatables-advanced-filtering)  or try changing the type to just date. That should properly sort. You would only need to use the extend option to define your own custom sort if you need something else that what type date accomplishes.